# "for you" or "for yourself" in context?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please what word is correct to use in the following sentence.

> Just press the handlebar to adjust the seat for **you**/**yourself**.

Comment: Either (or neither) would be fine, and would *normally* all mean the same thing (adjust the seat to suit *your* size / shape). But if the speaker wanted to imply ***You** should make the adjustment (don't expect me or anyone else to do it for you)* then only explicitly reflexive ***yourself*** could convey that sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Yourself' would be better in this sentence.  In this case, it is to emphasize that the person being addressed will take the action instead of someone else.  If you don't want to emphasize that, I would leave out 'you/yourself' altogether.